# How do urls without get parameters work

Tags: php, url

Hi i have come across some urls of the type `"http://localhost/jsfweb/cat/query/"` where query is a string that will return some results from a mysql database. I am familiar with urls of the type `"http://localhost/jsfweb/cat.php?query=query"` how can i use those urls with php?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_URL

Comment: Can you imagine that this question has been asked in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modrewrite

You do something like this:
Inside a file named '.htaccess'

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /php/eclipse/ShiftPlus2/

#forbidden area
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$                               http://localhost/php/eclipse/ShiftPlus2/?   [R=301]

#unique case
RewriteRule ^email$ email.html [L]

#general case
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]*)/?$                                    index.php?query=$1                   [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-z]+)/?$                           index.php?query=$1&action=$2          [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/(-?\d+)/?$                            index.php?query=$1&id=$2              [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-z]+)/(-?\d+)/?$                   index.php?query=$1&action=$2$id=$3   [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/(\w+)/?$                              index.php?query=$1&special=$2         [L]

#RewriteRule ^index.php$ login [R]
```

Where on the left side, there is a Rewrite rule with a regular expression and on the right, this is the real link like you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by rewriting url in htaccess file by this :

RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)$ cat.php?query=$1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache's mod_rewrite. For most of the websites it is done through that module. If you don't want to get your hands dirty with it, you can employ some sort of MVC framework that incorporates it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache mod_rewrite is what you want.  This is an excellent read for beginners:

[10 Mod Rewrite Rules You Should Know](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html)

Answer (score 0):

[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) (MVC framework) works by accepting a single entry point to the application, then routing according to what follows.  So say you declare *index.php* as the default document, then **/index.php/controller/view** is the same as **/controller/view**.  The parameters *controller* and *view* are used to instantiate and run the appropriate classes.